# Can I align all the tables in an org file from the command line?

Tags: org-mode

I have some org files that I generated from a program I wrote. My program is not intelligent enough to parse the tables in these files "correctly". For example, one of my org files may look like

```
#+Title: hello world

* section 1

here is an unaligned table

|this |is | my |
| first| unaligned| table |

* section 2

here are two more unaligned tables

| this | is |my |
|second| unaligned |     table|

|yet|another| unaligned|
|table| to |alter|
```

I'd like to be able to automatically align all the tables in these files from the command line. Thus running such a command on my above file would yield

```
#+Title: hello world

* section 1

here is an unaligned table

| this  | is        | my    |
| first | unaligned | table |

* section 2

here are two more unaligned tables

| this   | is        | my    |
| second | unaligned | table |

| yet   | another | unaligned |
| table | to      | alter     |
```

Does such a command exist?

I'm aware that setting `org-startup-align-all-tables` to `t` will automatically align every table upon visiting the file but I'd like to align the tables without actually opening the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no command to do what you want, but in emacs we can have our way

I have wrote a small shell script based on the tangle [example](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Batch-execution)  in the emacs manual

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- mode: shell-script -*-
#
# tangle files with org-mode
#
DIR=`pwd`
FILES=""

# wrap each argument in the code required to call tangle on it
for i in $@; do
FILES="$FILES \"$i\""
done

emacs -Q --batch \
--eval "(progn
     (require 'org)(require 'org-table)
     (mapc (lambda (file)
            (find-file (expand-file-name file \"$DIR\"))
            (org-table-map-tables 'org-table-align)
            (write-file file nil)
            (kill-buffer)) '($FILES)))"
```

Be aware that the script overwrites the original file

Comment: How does that align tables as op wants?

Comment: To my understanding OP has the files with unaligned tables, and wants to align them as Org would do when opening a file.
I tested the script and it did that
PLease pay attention to the "org-table-map" line

Comment: Well, this works perfectly! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Joafigue I wonder if this script could be altered to also update all the formulas in the tables... Would that be an easy alteration or should I ask a separate question?

Comment: Ahh.. figured it out. Replacing `'org-table-align` with `'org-table-iterate` does the trick.

Comment: @Joafigue How would I apply this script to all the org files in a directory?

Comment: Hi Brian,
To apply the script to all the files, you can use your favorite shell tricks; The easiest way I think is to use glob expansion
If the script is named "align_tables.sh" you can use
     
`$ align_tables.sh dir/*.org`

Answer (score 3):

> Does such a command exist?

No, but you can easily mimic in a variety of ways. The easiest approach seems an adaptation of org-mode's built-in [column alignment overrides](http://orgmode.org/manual/Column-width-and-alignment.html#Column-width-and-alignment) `<10>` at the top of each column. For example:

```
| <8>    |    <11>   |   <12>    |
| this   | is        | my        |
| second | unaligned | table     |
```

your second table

```
| <8>    |    <11>   |   <12>    |
| yet    | another   | unaligned |
| table  | to        | alter     |
```

where `<8>`, `<11>` and `<12>` are arbitrary column widths that you specify for each column of each table, overriding the automatic alignment. This will have the effect of aligning all the columns and the tables.

I can confirm I've used this feature extensively while dumping to html.

Addendum:

To print in orgmode, you must invoke the export to text feature:

```
C-c C-e t a
```

There are [other options](http://orgmode.org/org.html#ASCII_002fLatin_002d1_002fUTF_002d8-export) to save to file, save to a new buffer, etc. If you want to export from the command line, use one like this:

```
emacs foo.org --batch -f org-ascii-export-to-ascii --kill
```

The manual has more details about [batch execution](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Batch-execution).

Comment: This doesn't seem to to accomplish what I'd like. Issuing `cat foo.org` on my  file still yields an unaligned table.

Comment: `cat` won't work, see the updated `addendum` in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In an `org` file I have several named code blocks, some of them generate (`#+RESULTS`) named tables.  Whenever I want to regenerate the tables in the file, I run `org-babel-execute-buffer`, and then I end up in a situation pretty much similar to yours, that is with unaligned tabled.

Well, I should say I "would" end up in such situation, but in fact the latest code block in the file does the alignment for me:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output silent
  (org-table-map-tables 'org-table-align)
#+END_SRC
```

This block applies in fact what is used in the selected answer.  By including this block at the end, after generating all the tables they are automatically re-aligned.